# How to `$inject` factory service in to a `service module`?

Tags: angularjs

I have a `factory` module called `server'. for some reasons i have created a generic web service in a`service`module. but when i`inject`the server module, i am getting result as`undefined`

how to solve this?

this is my `factory` module :

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("tcpApp")
        .factory("server", ['$resource', function ($resource) {

            var base = 'http://azvsptcsdev02:678/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/';

            return {

                batchUpdate : $resource( base + 'UpdateImportantbyUser')

            }

        }]);

})();
```

this is my web service, where the `server` module requires.

```
"use strict";
angular.module("tcpApp").service("batchService", ['server', function ( $rootScope, server ) {

    console.log( server ); // consoles as undefined

    server.batchUpdate.save({ //i need to use the server serice

            "Id" : newId,
            "Type" : newType,
            "IsImportant"  : newImportant

        })
        .$promise.then(function(response) {

            console.log(response);
            object.IsImportant = newImportant;

        });

}]);
```

how to solve this? what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you have missed to annotate a the `$rootScope` dependency,

What happen in your problem is `$rootScope` getting the injected `service` and `service` getting nothing.

try to `console.log($rootScope);` it will print your injected `server`.

SO the correct format would be like this,

```
angular.module("tcpApp").service("batchService", ['$rootScope', 'server', function ( $rootScope, server ) {
```

for more read this [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)